# Three.js r49 shows INVALID_OPERATION on Mac OS X with Chrome 27

Tags: macos, google-chrome, three.js, webgl

Three.js r49 shows INVALID_OPERATION in drawElements() call in THREE.WebGLRenderer.renderBuffer method (WebGLRenderer.js, line 3152): "INVALID_OPERATION: drawElements: attribs not setup correctly".

The rendering result is blank screen.

The PC version of Chrome 27 works just fine (Windows 7 64-bit); pre-27 builds of Chrome worked for me on OS X too.

Comment: You need to bring your code to the current release r58. The release you are using is very old. You can find migration info at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration and change log info at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/

Comment: Well, that's the good point, but it is not so easy to do (I've tried r49 -> r57 migration and it needs debugging for our custom postprocess pass which doesn't work as-is with r57). So the quick'n'dirty solution is to fix my r49 build instead.